# Property 'web' does not exist on type 'SPRest'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js-core, office-dev-pnp, npm

I installed these packages: **@pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/sp**

```
npm i @pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/sp --save
```

and tried this:

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';

public componentDidMount() {
  sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.pageContext.list.id.toString())
    .items.getById(this.props.pageContext.listItem.id)
      .select("Department,FreeText")
        .get()
          .then(d => {
            console.log(d);

            this.setState({
              department: d.Department,
              freeText: d.FreeText
            });
          });
}
```

But got the error:

```
Property 'web' does not exist on type 'SPRest'.ts(2339)
```

When I tried also to import **Web** from **@pnp/sp** I got this error:

```
node_modules/@pnp/sp"' has no exported member 'Web'.
```

What is the problem?

**EDIT:**

My main webpart typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';


import * as strings from 'TryWebPartStrings';
import Try from './components/Try';
import { ITryProps } from './components/ITryProps';

import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';

export interface ITryWebPartProps {
  description: string;

}

export default class TryWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITryWebPartProps> {


  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      sp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });
    });
  }

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ITryProps > = React.createElement(
      Try,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        pageContext: this.context.pageContext
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

Version of @pnp/sp is: **@pnp/sp@2.0.0**

Comment: Which version of pnpjs you are using?

Comment: Version of @pnp/sp is: @pnp/sp@2.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the previous versions 'web' was still present in the rest.d.ts file of the @pnp/sp package. That's not the case anymore. In your main webpart TypeScript file, you have to use the import as follow:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

Answer (score 1):

In IReactSpfxProps.ts file:

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

    export interface IReactSpfxProps {
      description: string;
      context: WebPartContext;
    }
```

WebPart.ts:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'ReactSpfxWebPartStrings';
import ReactSpfx from './components/ReactSpfx';
import { IReactSpfxProps} from './components/IReactSpfxProps';
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";


export default class ReactSpfxWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IReactSpfxProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IReactSpfxProps> = React.createElement(
      ReactSpfx,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context: this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {

    return super.onInit().then(_ => {

      pnp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });

    });
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

tsx:

```
 public componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.context.pageContext.list.id.toString());
    console.log(this.props.context.pageContext.listItem.id.toString());
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.context.pageContext.list.id.toString())
    .items.getById(this.props.context.pageContext.listItem.id)
      .select("Department,FreeText")
        .get()
          .then(d => {
            console.log(d);
          });

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the PnP JS context in your main webpart typescript file like below:

```
sp.setup({
    spfxContext: this.context
});
```

Try following the steps given at:

[SPFX Load SharePoint list items in a dropdown using PNP SP JS](http://www.sharepointsamples.com/spfx-load-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-dropdown-using-pnp-sp-js/).

Comment: I edited the question so you can consult the content of main webpart typescript

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in the code:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

Remove below line from code:

```
import {sp} from '@pnp/sp';
```